# How to convert HtmlImage Object to RenderedImage?

Tags: java, image, htmlunit

I have such method, it's try to download images:

```
private static void downloadImage() throws IOException {
            int imgSrc = 0;
            for(HtmlImage img : urlList){ 
                String imageFormat = img.toString().substring(img.toString().lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
                String imgPath = "C:\\" + imgSrc + "";
                imgSrc++;
                if (img != null) {
                    File file = new File(imgPath);
                    //In the next method i need img in RenderedImage type
                    ImageIO.write(img, imageFormat, file);
                }
            }  
        }
```

How I can convert it `HtmlImage img` => `RenderedImage img`?

Comment: Are you just trying to save an HtmlImage to a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, in which you mentioned you're just trying to save an `HtmlImage` to a file, then the simplest way is to use the [`saveAs(File file)`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlImage.html#saveAs%28java.io.File%29) method of the `HtmlImage` class.

Your code would look something like this:

```
if (img != null) {
    File file = new File(imgPath);
    img.saveAs(file);
}
```

Bear in mind, that method might throw an `IOException`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a `RenderedImage` directly, without saving to a file:

```
private RenderedImage getImage(HtmlImage image) throws IOException {
    ImageReader reader = image.getImageReader();
    int minIndex = reader.getMinIndex();
    return reader.read(minIndex);
}
```

Here is a working example:

```
package org.human.joecoder.htmlunit;

import java.awt.image.RenderedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.imageio.ImageReader;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlImage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;

public class HtmlUnitImageScraper {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        HtmlPage currentPage = (HtmlPage) webClient.getPage(new URL(
                "http://www.google.com"));
        final List<?> images = currentPage.getByXPath("//img");
        for (int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++) {
            Object imageObject = images.get(i);
            HtmlImage image = (HtmlImage) imageObject;
            RenderedImage buf = getImage(image);
            ImageIO.write(buf, "png", new File("image_"+i+".png"));
        }
        webClient.closeAllWindows();
    }

    private static RenderedImage getImage(HtmlImage image) throws IOException {
        ImageReader reader = image.getImageReader();
        int minIndex = reader.getMinIndex();
        return reader.read(minIndex);
    }
}
```